# What is wrong with my approach? What error did I make mathematically?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, calculus

> **A $4$ kg object is moving in one dimension along the x-axis. The linear momentum of the object increases with the position of the object according to the following equation:**
>
> **$p(x)=6+3x$**
>
> **At $t = 0$ s the object is at $x = 0$ m. Where is the object (in m) at $t = 4$ s?**

we have $$6+3x=4(dx/dt)$$ and then $$(6+3x)dt=4dx$$

integrate on both sides and get

$$\left(6tx+3xt)\right|^4_0=4(x_f-x_i)$$

When I plug in and solve for $x$ I get an incorrect answer. The actual solution, given by the book, moves all $x$ terms to the side where we integrate with respect to x. why is this moving all x terms to the side with the dx even necessary before integrating? I am aware of nothing from my calculus classes that require this sort of approach to solving an equation using integrals.

Comment: Hi @bfff, and welcome to Physics SE! Please take a few moments to read our [help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) and in particular our policy on [homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/106502). There might be a relevant question in your post, but in its current form it is likely to be closed as a homework problem.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. You can take this as a warning. Any attempt to vandalize you post may result in a temporary suspension and locking of your post.

Answer (score 2):

yeah you did mistake in your math

$(6+3x)dt=4dx$

here $x$ is variable because as time varies,the particle will be at different places. so,$x$ is varying with time.  you cant integrate a variable withrespective other variable. so $(6+3x)$ should be sent other side

so the correct process is

$dt$=$\frac{4}{6+3x}$$dx$
now integrate on both sides you will get required answer

I think you can proceed now

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more? I dont understand why the (6+3x) cannot be treated as a constant when it is on the "dt" side of the equation. If it was on the dx side of the equation, then obviously I see why we have to integrate it. Why can I not just leave it on the "dt" side. We did this all the time in calc 3: for example there is no problem with saying that the integral of y with respect to x is yx...

Comment: @bfff "Why (6+3x) can't be treated as a constant..."---even when it is on dt side of the equation,x is a function of t.$\int xdt$=$\int x(t) dt$,we cannot take the x out of the integration symbol when x is a function of t,because with t, the value of x also gets changed.

Comment: @Charan T, this is not true. y must be treated as a constant as part of the process, but can also be a variable for the integral  of y with respect to x to be yx

Comment: @bfff if this is true then ,let y=x be a function now find integral of y withrespect to x then your answer is yx which is $x^2$ but when you substitute y=x in integration you will get $x^2/2$ which is contradictory to your statement.your statement is true when y is independent of x but in your problem x is dependent on time so you cant do the way you did

Comment: okay but your statement " integral of y withrespect to x is yx if and only if y is constant" is not true. What I am starting to understand is that it should say " integral of y withrespect to x is yx if and only if y is not a function of x"

Comment: @bfff yes you are correct